# Is it possible to start windows with NUM Lock on?

Tags: windows

A password is always combination of characters & numbers. I am so much used to num pad that every time windows start I end up entering wrong password just because NUM lock isn't ON by default. Since it's network login, it takes a bit long time to reset & prompt for right password. Is there a way to enable NUM Lock on when Windows loads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an article in the Microsoft KB on [How to enable the NUM LOCK key for the logon screen](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154529).

Answer (score 7):

There is also a 'boot with numlock on' setting in most modern bioses.

Comment: yeah, do it in BIOS.