# Enable numlock on a laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, numlock

I know there should usually be <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>some key</kbd> but on my Envy 17 3D there is no such combination.

1. I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> + everything, it does not change anything
2. Tried to look in BIOS, no luck there
3. Tried to find something like that in the registry - couldn't find anything

Is there a way to enable numlock? It was ON before, but now for some reason it isn't working and instead of number keys I get directional keys and stuff like end, home, etc.

Comment: It's rather strange. I've looked around Google Images and found out that a lot of HP Envy 17 3D around 2012 do have a numlock key on the numpad. But some around 2011 have page down in the position of the num lock key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I referred on a comment, most Windows OS since XP have an option called Virtual Keyboard that emulates a keyboard on the main display. It is used mostly for people that can't use a keyboard or that by some chance can't use one. You can from that select Num Lock.

Besides this, check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/496845/how-to-have-num-lock-enabled-by-default-on-log-on-screen) question, as it might give you a permanent solution.

On Windows XP, you can access it through Start Menu >> All Programs >> Accessories >> Accessibility >> On-Screen Keyboard or through `Windows Key + U` ([source](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/osk_overview.mspx?mfr=true))

On Windows Vista and apparently Windows 8, you can access it through Start >> Control Panel >> Ease of Access >> On-Screen Keyboard ([source](http://www.ehow.com/how_6558537_turn-keyboard-windows-vista-basic.html))([Windows 8 source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/type-with-the-on-screen-keyboard)). Otherwise, you can access it through the previous method, with the difference being that Accessibility = Ease of Access ([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/type-without-keyboard#type-without-keyboard=windows-7))

Both Windows XP and Windows Vista have the same virtual keyboard. The Num Lock is represented by the `nlk` button.

[image: Windows Vista On-Screen Keyboard]

Windows 7 has a different style. I believe that Num Lock is hidden in the `Options` button.

[image: Windows 7 On-Screen Keyboard]

Windows 8 has, besides the On-Screen Keyboard, a new plethora of touch-based interfaces. In  the Options dialog, you can check the box to "Turn on numeric key pad." This provides a NumLock button on the on-screen keyboard.

[image: Windows 8 On-Screen Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can start the [Onboard Keyboard](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/onboard/) there you click on the Numberpad-Button <kbd>123</kbd> where you have a <kbd>NumLock</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your Dell laptop has a LOCK ICON on the kepad 9 key then someone has pressed [F3]+[9].  Press them both together to toggle your numlock.