# Windows 8.1 Numlock on logon

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, numlock, numpad

I know this has been asked before, but none of those answers work for me.
I've got Windows 8.1 installed on my pc and my user password contains numbers.
I'm used to use the numpad for typing numbers, but everytime i boot up my pc its turned off.

I've checked the BIOS and it says that numlock **is** enabled at startup, i can even see that in the boot screen, its turned on there.

I've also tried changing the registry values. Some say a value of **2** does what I want, some say **2147483650**. Both values do not change the numlock state at login, a value of **2147483650** even gets reverted back to **2** when i boot my pc next time.

I really dont know whats left there to try, so please help me

Comment: `2147483650` is equal to `2` in binary which is the reason it convert itself to 2 because the value is the same.  I am not going to explain the reason in detail just thought you should know the two values are actually the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have num lock enabled by default on log on screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/496845/how-to-have-num-lock-enabled-by-default-on-log-on-screen)