# Windows 7 - How to turn numlock on initially when windows starts?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, numlock, numpad

I have windows 7 and my password is numeric. When I start windows I always try to enter password with numpad and when it fails I see numlock is off. How should I change this behavior in windows?

I want the default keyboard options always to be "**on** for <kbd>Numlock</kbd>" and "**off** for <kbd>Capslock</kbd> and <kbd>Scrolllock</kbd> at my windows startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable NUM LOCK before a user logs on, follow these steps:

```
Run Registry Editor.

Move to

HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\Keyboard
.

Change the value for InitialKeyboardIndicators from 0 to 2.
```

This should hopefully set NUM LOCK as soon as the login screen appears.

Comment: But the value is not 0. It's 2147483648 in my registry editor.

Comment: @Mojtaba - Have you tried changing it?

Comment: @Mojtaba Change it to 2 and restart your machine. Probably safe to take a backup of your Registry too just in case :)

Comment: -2147483648 is the lower bound for a 32-bit int. it is interpreted as null for all intents and purposes. Replace it with 2, and your numlock should come on at OS boot.

Comment: The number "2147483648" is the hexadecimal equivalent of 0x80000000

Comment: I've got my answer, seems it's working fine now, thanks all!

Comment: As a useful comment for this issue I found other values of this key: `1 = capslock`, `2 = numlock`, `4 = scrolllock` and you can combine any of them by simple add, for example to keep scroll lock and caps-lock on, use value `5` which will be sum of `4 = scrolllock` and `1 = capslock`

Comment: You may need to search the registry for **all** occurrences of InitialKeyboardIndicators and set them all to 2.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for a relative quite some time ago. Search for "InitialKeyboardIndicators" in your registry. It should be somewhere in HKEY_Users. Experiment with the settings. I think "2" is NumLock on, CapsLock off.

Comment: @FrankThomas - If thats the case, I trust you on that, I reversed the downvote and will delete that comment.